# SQL - How to calculate total of selected data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table populated with 6122 rows. I found all duplicates and displayed them. This is what I got:

```
description   grossSale  vat       netSale
produce 0055  268        50.11     217.89
product 0055  268        50.11     217.89
product 0009  339        63.39     275.61
product 0065  829        155.29    673.98
```

I now want the table to display the total of grossSale, vat and netSale. If I use sum(grossSale) grossSale, it gives me the sum of all 6122 value, but I only want the 4 that are displayed. So the table will look like this:

```
description   grossSale  vat       netSale
produce 0055  268        50.11     217.89
product 0055  268        50.11     217.89
product 0009  339        63.39     275.61
product 0065  829        155.29    673.98
              1704       318.9     1385.37
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the duplicates query you already have as a virtual table:

```
SELECT SUM (grossSale) grossSale,  SUM(vat) vat, SUM(netSale) netSale FROM
    (SQL to show duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `SELECT` statement that will select from your results. Just wrap your current `select` statement with another `SELECT` that will do `SUM` and `GROUP BY` your `Description`

```
SELECT Description
   ,SUM(grossSale)
   ,SUM(Vat)
   ,SUM(netSale)
FROM ( SELECT Description
           ,grossSale
           ,Vat
           ,netSale
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE MyColumn = 'SomeValue' ) a
GROUP BY Description
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `group by with rollup`.  You do have to do a `group by` first:

```
select description, sum(grossSale), sum(vat), sum(netSale)
from table t
group by description, grossSale, vat, netSale with rollup;
```

It may look odd to have the same columns in `sum()` as in the `group by`.  This is because your rows don't seem to have a unique identifier.  The `sum()` is needed so the `rollup` knows which columns to summarize.

Comment: This will show the sums for the whole table. The sum of the duplicates only is what is requested.

Comment: @DanielB . . . The example results in the question have both the original data and the summaries.